# Output PDF on server using html2pdf library

Tags: javascript, base64, data-uri, html2pdf

I am using the html2pdf javascript library to generate a PDF.
I want to store the PDF in the database, using the following code.

```
var element = document.getElementById('mydiv');
html2pdf().from(element).toPdf().output('datauristring').then(function (pdfAsString) {
console.log(pdfAsString);
// Here comes some ajax to store pdfAsString in my database
});
```

So far so good, this is working well. I now want to create a downloadable PDF file when I click on a link. I am using the following PHP to create the PDF file.

```
$data = $mybase64string;
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
echo $data;
```

I thought this would be working, but it just gives me an error, that the document can not be created.

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks :-)

Comment: *So far so good, this is working well.* the upload is working? but download fails? could you extract the pdf from database directly and make sure it is readable?

Comment: I store the datauristring, generated by the library.. When I check the string in the database "data:application/pdf;base64...", it is exactly the same like the console.log() outputs. So if there would be a problem with the string, then the function should have a bug.

Comment: may you post the whole error? because to me if the document can not be created you must have a serious problem right there

Comment: oh right, `$data = $mybase64string;` sending the data as base64 directly doesnt make it a proper pdf, you had to convert it to bytes array. how to do it is totally depend on your language, i presume its php, which you can use [`base64_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php). but remember to remove the `data:application/pdf;base64` prefix as it may broke the function.

Comment: Thank you! Removing the prefix before storing in the database, and calling base64_decode before generating the PDF did the magic :-)